# DexArchiveMergerException - java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distances set

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

When I'm trying to build code with android project below bug appear on android 3.0.1.

Please help me to resolve this error. I tried all the possible way to resolve but no luck.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distances set

Comment: Did it start appearing with any change to studio or gradle version?

Comment: After an update the studio also it worked fine, I tried to add some spring-core library from gradle and later on removed it and did the sync. From that moment it getting the error when building the app.

Comment: What else have you already tried? Clean build? Restarting the gradle daemon?

Comment: Yes, did all the things mentioned by you.
Delete the **.gradle** file, clean build